# CheckBox стиль. Android

Tags: android

Вопрос очень простой, но в силу того что английский плохо знаю, то сам не могу найти ответ на вопрос. В общем У меня есть `CheckBox`, не важно в каком он у меня положении, главное что он у меня не кликабельный, потому что из кода вызвал для него метод `setEnabled(false)` и получается так что `CheckBox` высвечивается серым цветом, то есть ни цветом отмеченного и не цветом неотмеченного (я про цвета определенные в стиле). Я так понимаю должен быть атрибут для стиля, который задает этот цвет, только вот найти этот атрибут я не могу. Помогите, заранее спасибо!

Comment: [`android:state_enabled`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList)?

Comment: а причем тут это, мне нужен атрибут для того чтобы задать цвет в стиле

Comment: Вам нужен атрибут, который бы применялся непосредственно к `CheckBox` при его размещении в `layout`-файле?

Comment: Посмотрите [сюда](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17524259), насколько я понимаю, Вам нужно изменить там `<!-- Disabled states -->`.

Comment: изменить этот цвет вы можете переписав селектор чекбокса, просто так указать цвет нельзя.

Comment: такого атрибут  нет. Вам придется сделать ему новый `android:state_enabled`, как сказал @post_zeew

Answer (score 1):

Всё просто, **можно сделать вот так:**

Допустим вот твой `CheckBox`:

```
<CheckBox
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:background="@drawable/checkbox_background" />
```

А вот и сам **checkbox_background.xml** файл в котором хранятся параметры вида `CheckBox`’а в зависимости от его состояния (он должен лежать в папке `drawable`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <item android:state_checked="true"
       android:state_focused="true"
       android:state_enabled="true"
       android:drawable="@drawable/checkbox_on_background_focus_yellow" />

 <item android:state_checked="false" 
       android:state_focused="true"
       android:state_enabled="true"
       android:drawable="@drawable/checkbox_off_background_focus_yellow" />

 <item android:state_checked="false"
       android:state_enabled="true"
       android:drawable="@drawable/checkbox_off_background" />

 <item android:state_checked="true"
       android:state_enabled="true"
       android:drawable="@drawable/checkbox_on_background" />

 <item android:state_checked="false"
       android:state_enabled="false"
       android:drawable="@drawable/checkbox_off_background" />

 <item android:state_checked="true"
       android:state_enabled="false"
       android:drawable="@drawable/checkbox_on_background" />
</selector>
```

Здесь каждый `item` отвечает за какое-то состояние (какое именно описано параметрами внутри `item`).
А интересующий тебя параметр здесь `android:state_enabled="false`

Так что последние 2 **item**'a внутри **selector**'a отвечают за вид **CheckBox**’а в отключённом состоянии в положении "не чекнут" и "чекнут" соответственно.

Comment: Этот checkbox_background.xml так же можно указать в стиле как background