# Spinner стиль. Android

Tags: android, style

У меня есть Spinner, я хочу изменить его стиль, а именно, изменить цвет стрелки и изменить цвет выбранного варианта. Как это сделать? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: По аналогии [с этим](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/576675/checkbox-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C-android). Подробнее [тут](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/design/spinner-style.php).

Comment: "цвет" стрелки не задается. Стрелка - это часть фона. Да, она именно нарисована на фоне спиннера.